# Is it possible to sync exchange emails via activesync if we use SSO?

Tags: single-sign-on, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm using activesync to sync exchange emails, where the authentication happens using basic auth. I was wondering if it's possible to use activesync with a single sign-on solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to implement SSO on ActiveSync is with Certificate based authentication. ActiveSync has no support for identity federation, hence no SAML, OAuth, ... Setting up an internal CA is not that complicated, especially if you use Microsoft's CA: ADCS. Simply follow the instructions in the link from BastianW. 
You will then need an Enterprise Mobility Management tool like [AirWatch](https://air-watch.com), [MobileIron](https://mobileiron.com), ... to integrate with your CA and distribute the certificates seamlessly to your users.

Answer (score 0):

I assume with SSO you wish to implement a way where your users can use there mobile phones without the need to adjust her password every time when they change there password inside the active directory. The solution to do that is using "[certificate-based authentication for Exchange ActiveSync](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2012/11/28/configure-certificate-based-authentication-for-exchange-activesync/)". Via that approach an internal CA will create an certificate for the user which can be used on the mobile device to authenticate an ActiveSync session against your Exchange environment. As long as the certificate is valid the user can use that on there mobile device instead of an password.

Keep noted that this required a higher workload for the IT department (for most my customers) so most of them started to use a MDM environment which can push these certificates to the enrolled devices nearly automatically. AirWatch for example can do that (but there might be other, however I can only speak from AirWatch as this is in use by 6 customers).

And just another advise how we build that: We added additional IPs to the Exchange environment then configured an additional ActiveSync side with certificate authenticated. Then we could test the whole solution and later one switch over the user. But if you do not have that much users you might considering a "big bang" migration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually have an app that allows users to sync Exchange emails (via activesync), but one of my users uses Okta for SSO. So was wondering how to get that to work, since activesync seems to be Basic Auth based

Answer (score 0):

Simple activesync via BasicAuth is not really "the way".

E.g.: Airwatch is using the "Mobile Email Management", which works like an Proxy to your network. Working that way, you can use SSO via AD / LDAP and so on...

I would highly recommend doing it that way.